# Differences between FnOnce and impl FnOnce when i use them as function parameter in rust

Tags: rust

```rust
pub trait TransactionManager<D, R, F>: DatabaseManager
where
    D: DatabaseManager,
    F: FnOnce(D) -> Result<R, Error>,
{
    fn execute_in_transaction(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<R, Error>;
}

pub async fn create_vote<D, T, F>(mut manager: T, data: VoteInsertion) -> Result<i32, Error>
where
    D: DatabaseManager,
    T: TransactionManager<D, i32, F>,
    F: FnOnce(D) -> Result<i32, Error>,
{
    manager.execute_in_transaction(|mut manager: D| manager.insert(data))
}
```

above code, the compiler will complain:

> mismatched types
> expected type parameter `F`
> found closure `[closure@src/core/vote.rs:21:36: 21:52]`
> every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `F`

but if I modify it to be like below

```rust
pub trait TransactionManager<D, R>: DatabaseManager
where
    D: DatabaseManager,
{
    fn execute_in_transaction(&mut self, f: impl FnOnce(D) -> Result<R, Error>) -> Result<R, Error>;
}

pub async fn create_vote<D, T>(mut manager: T, data: VoteInsertion) -> Result<i32, Error>
where
    D: DatabaseManager,
    T: TransactionManager<D, i32>,
{
    manager.execute_in_transaction(|mut manager: D| manager.insert(data))
}
```

everything will be ok

In my own view, `f: F` also means `f` must implement `F` trait, why must I use `impl FnOnce(D)` to express this meaning?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is who defines the generic.

In the first snippet, the type parameter `F` is a parameter of the trait, and in `create_vote()` you take it as generic so it is some specific type. This type does not match the type of the closure inside `create_vote()`, so this is an error. You would need something like `for<F: FnOnce(D) -> Result<R, Error>>`, but this doesn't exist.

In the second snippet, the type parameter is a parameter of the `execute_in_transaction()` method, and any type that implements `FnOnce` can be used for it, and that includes the closure inside `create_vote()`.

You don't have to use `impl Trait`, you can also use usual generic syntax:

```rust
pub trait TransactionManager<D, R>: DatabaseManager
where
    D: DatabaseManager,
{
    fn execute_in_transaction<F: FnOnce(D) -> Result<R, Error>>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<R, Error>;
}
```

Comment: when I use a trait as a specific type, its member methods can still be abstracted?

Comment: Yes, member methods can be abstracted. A trait method that takes (non-lifetime) generic arguments is not object-safe (and so cannot be called from a `dyn Trait` object), but they can still be used in ordinary generics.